# My input fields render inline on IE, but on new lines in Chrome and Firefox. How can I fix that?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-rendering

What do I need to change to make Chrome and Firefox render the same way as Internet Explorer? My first idea was to use CSS `calc()`, but I still need to support IE8.

I have the following CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Width300
{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

.Field
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

label
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

input
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.LabelSize100 .Field
{
    margin-right: 100px;    
}

.LabelSize100 label
{
    width: 100px;
}

.LabelSize100 input
{
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
<div class="LabelSize100 Width300">
    <div class="Field">
        <label>test:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="Field">
        <label>test:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the result is totally different in IE/Chrome and FF:
[image: GUI Error]

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3u3jg3y3/1/)

Comment: Is it because you're not using a normalize CSS file?

Comment: @PoeHaH, the .Field was a miss type the issue still presists if you remove it!

Comment: Peter, this reply is not for me :) re-read my question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `display:inline-block;` to `<label>` and `<input>`

**CSS**

```
label
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

input
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.LabelSize100 input
{
 // Remove margin-left
}
```

Note: remove `margin-left`from `<input>`

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3u3jg3y3/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="LabelSize100 Width300">
    <div class="Field">
        <label>test:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="Field">
        <label>test:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Width300 {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
.Field {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding: 1px 0;
    width:100%;
}
label {
    float: left;
}
input {
    display: block;
    float:right;
}
.LabelSize100 .Field {
      margin-right: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.LabelSize100 label {
    width: 100px;
}
```

And [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u3jg3y3/7/)

Seems to work on all 3 browsers

Comment: The input should cover the rest of the area, look in this example http://jsfiddle.net/3u3jg3y3/9/ the second form dosent adapt the way i want it to..

Comment: Ah - I thought your problem was: both label and input do not display in one line, next to each other. And yes, you're right - to achieve what you want (input field to stretch to whole remaining space horizontally), you'll need to use `calc()` function.  `width: calc(100% - 100px);`. And fallback is hardcoded / fixed width placed just before above rule in css: `width: 200px;` and then `width: calc(100% - 100px);` straight after that. I can also see a potential for flexbox here - but I need to play with it, and eventually post it as a second answer, as I work out solution.

Comment: ...meanwhile, you can try and test this little hack: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/3u3jg3y3/18/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax, look at class `.Field

```
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding: 1px 0;.Field
}
```

`.Field` should not be after `padding`

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Width300
{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

.Field
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

label
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

input
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.LabelSize100 .Field
{
    margin-right: 100px;    
}

.LabelSize100 label
{
    width: 100px;
}

.LabelSize100 input
{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="LabelSize100 Width300">
    <div class="Field">
        <label>test:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="Field">
        <label>test:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that was a misstype, but even if i remove it the issue presists!

Answer (score 0):

You should include a normalize CSS file. It's a file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. Download this file and include it before your CSS: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/